# The best way to make Angular optimizations

Tags: angularjs

Ok, so yes this question is a bit open ended but seriously I'd love some help. What are some ways that I can optimize my angular application? I'm using ng-bind instead of the double curlies, no services in my controllers, reducing the amount of objects in the `$scope` but what else is there? Is there anything obvious and big that I'm missing? Thanks in advance for our help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. $scope.$apply() vs. $scope.$digest()

Instead of using `$scope.$apply`, use `$scope.$digest` which runs the exact same `$digest` loop as `$scope.$apply`. However, it is executed from the current $scope downwards through its children which is a much more performance friendly loop.

## 2. Avoid using ng-repeat where ever possible

The `ng-repeat` directive is probably the worst offender for performance concerns, which means it can easily be abused. An `ng-repeat` creates a lot of `$scope` bindings which creates more watchers and has a dig at the `$digest` cycle's perfomance.

## 3. Do more of your DOM manipulation in directives

Something that will increase your `$$watcher` count is using a lot of show/hide logic with `ng-show` and `ng-hide`. Should you perform this in directives without binding the logic to the `$scope`, you will increase the perfomance and have less watchers.

## 4. Be careful using DOM filters

Angular runs every single filter twice per `$digest` cycle once something has changed. The first run is from the `$$watchers`, detecting any changes made, the second run is to see if there are further changes that need updated values.

Angular provides a way to preprocess the filters, using `$filter`, which will process the data in Javascript before passing it on to the DOM.

These are just a few things but you can get an idea of how to take actions to increase performance.

Kudos to https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135

You can just Google and you'll probably come up with a million articles explaining this.

Comment: Can you also post the source url for this? I believe I saw the same list somewhere...

Comment: @JCS Forgot it, now it's there :)

Comment: That was it! Thank you :)